# Sudden segmentation during boot when running Ubuntu 12.04 on DELL XPS 2720

Tags: ubuntu

I have to install Ubuntu on a PC at my university and after successfully installing it using the installer available by live boot I come across such a crash when I try to boot it up:

[image]

At this runlevel it's quite difficult to get a copy of the text on screen, so I had to take the analog hole to get a 'screenshot' for you :P

This is quite uninformative for me, could anybody please give me some hints as to what could cause this problem? 
The hardware config:

- 4th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-4460S Processor (6M Cache, up to 3.40 GHz)
- 27 inch LED Backlit Touch Display with IPS/Anti Glare and Adobe RGB QHD resolution (2560 X 1440)
- 16GB Dual Channel DDR3 1600MHz (8GBx2)
- 1TB 7200 rpm Hard Drive
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GT 750M 2GB GDDR5
- Slot load DVD Drive 9.5
- wireless: Intel® 7260AC+BT4.0 (not sure)
- Audio: Integrated 5.1 with WAVES MAXXAudio 4

If there's a need for any more hardware details, I'll have to provide them when I can physically access the computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

> RIP: ... (some stuff)...  [nouveau]

is telling you that your pc is crashing because of some bug inside the nouveau drivers.

You may manage to boot by hitting <kbd>e</kbd> when the GRUB menu shows up, then changing the line

```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff quiet splash
```

to

```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81-8048-4ae1-8a06-aa727458e8ff modprobe.blacklist=nouveau
```

You should be able to boot, this way, and start to investigate why the nouveau drivers are ill-configured on your machine. If you want to make the change permanent, you will have to edit the file `/etc/default/grub`, find the line

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=nouveau"
```

and then regenerate grub by means of

```
   sudo update-grub
```

As for the problem with `nouveau`, I think you should ask a different question, providing also some error messages to be found, most likely, in `/var/log/Xorg.*.log. The error messages will, presumably, be there after you try to start your graphic environment via CLI.

Comment: Thank You so much! I'll try that as soon as I'll get to lay my hands on this stuff. And, for clarification, regarding "start your graphic environment via CLI" - is it enough to type `startx` in some side-terminal like one of these accessed by 'Ctrl+Alt+F?' or do I need to force Ubuntu to boot without going to graphical interface by default and allow me to start the first machine-wide instance of Xorg manually?

Comment: @KrzysiekSetlak It depends on your Manager: what do you have, Gnome, KDE, Mate, LXDE, XFCE, ....

Comment: Unity (guess it's Gnome-based? I'm not sure)

Comment: @KrzysiekSetlak Then startx is Ok